# In SwiftUI, get warning while using animation() in TavView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I want implement OnBoard Screen in SwiftUI. For that reason, I used TabView. It works perfectly. But I got this warning 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0.  How I implement **withAnimation or animation(_:value:)** to fulfil my goal.

```
          VStack(spacing: 34) {
                TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.getOnBoards(), id: \.id) { onboard in
                        OnBoardItemView(onBoard: onboard)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                .transition(.slide)
                
                Spacer()
                
                ItemIndicatorView(
                    totalNumberOfItem: 3,
                    current: $currentIndex
                )
                
                ControllerView(
                    currentIndex: $currentIndex,
                    totalNumberOfItem: 3,
                    onboard: viewModel.getOnBoardItemAt(position: currentIndex-1)
                )

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from iOS 15, `animation(_:)` is deprecated but you can use `animation(_:value:)` by passing `currentIndex` into value parameter instead if you prefer the implicit animation approach. The code snippet will be as follows.

```swift
TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
    ForEach(viewModel.getOnBoards(), id: \.id) { onboard in
        OnBoardItemView(onBoard: onboard)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0), value: currentIndex)
.transition(.slide)
```

But you can also move to explicit animation using `withAnimation` to animate slide transition. For this approach, you need to wrap the line of code to switch the value of `currentIndex` inside `withAnimation` block. The code snippet will be as follows.

```swift
withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
    currentIndex = newValue
}
```

I hope this will help you to understand how to animate explicitly or implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need tell Xcode what exactly should be animated! With given a variable that conform to Equatable protocol. That could be State or Binding or any other wrapper that allow you to update the value of it.

```
VStack(spacing: 34) {
            TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
                ForEach(viewModel.getOnBoards(), id: \.id) { onboard in
                    OnBoardItemView(onBoard: onboard)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
            .transition(.slide)
            
            Spacer()
            
            ItemIndicatorView(
                totalNumberOfItem: 3,
                current: $currentIndex
            )
            
            ControllerView(
                currentIndex: $currentIndex,
                totalNumberOfItem: 3,
                onboard: viewModel.getOnBoardItemAt(position: currentIndex-1)
            )

        }
```